# Using NUnit for functional tests and guarantees about execution sequence and threads

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I asked this auestion on NUnit-Discuss, but i realize that group is not very active, so i give it a try here:

We've been using MSTests until now for some functional tests.
I know, neither MSTest nor NUnit is really for functional test, but we need those tests with a simple integration in Visual Studio.

The tests will launch other executables, connect, do stuff, disconnect and kill the processes.

We're having trouble with MSTest in that it launched tests in a separate thread and seems that some execution is overlapping between tests, even when executed sequentially.

So i'm thinking about moving to NUnit.

The question i have is:

Can NUnit be configured in any way such as to give the following guarantees:

- Tests will be executed sequentially, in an order that can be specified.
- Tests will be executed from the same thread.
- TearDown code of one test will have been fully executed before Setup code of a following test will be called.

If so, what would be that configuration, if any particular?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, NUnit does not execute any tests in parallel. If you never use the `ParallelizableAttribute`, then your tests run one at a time.

Of course, that does not mean your tests can't break NUnit, for example, by starting a thread or process that never terminates after the test thread terminates. NUnit only takes responsibility for the tests it runs itself.

NUnit does not guarantee that all tests will be executed from the same thread. That is a separate matter from parallelization, of course. Separate threads may be started for each thread, based on attributes you specify. You may, for example, designate some tests to run in a Single-threaded Apartment, while others run by default in an MTA. You might use the `RequiresThreadAttribute`, which asks NUnit to use a new thread for the test it decorates. You might use the `SingleThreadedAttribute` on a class, to indicate that all the code in that class runs on the same thread.

One trick, which is currently available but which may not exist in all future releases, is to specify --workers=0 on the command-line to nunit3-console. That tells NUnit to simply run the tests without creating any test workers and gives an execution path that more closely resembles that of NUnit V2.

So, in general, I think your needs can be met, but it could require some tinkering with your tests to make it work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks! Another question: If an exception is thrown during (OneTime)SetUp, will (OneTime)TearDown be called?